# copying an array of int*

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to create a copy constructor for my object, which look like this;

```
class DTable {
private:
    std::string s_name;
    int* *array;
    int size;

public:
    DTable();
    DTable(std::string sName);
    DTable(DTable &pcOther);
    ~DTable();

    void vSetName(std::string sName);
    std::string info();
    int getValue(int index, bool &ok);
    bool setValue(int index, int val);

    const int defaultArrSize = 10;
    const std::string defaultArrName = "Default Name";
};
```

Where array variable points at array of int*. Copy constructor i came up with looks like this;

```
DTable::DTable(DTable & pcOther) {
    s_name = pcOther.s_name + "_copy";
    size = pcOther.size;
    array = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = new int;
        *array[i] = pcOther.*array[i];
    }
}
```

The problem is that, i just cannot copy values of pointed int array to another array. Solution like this leaves me with error

> expression must have pointer to member type

Also,

```
array[i] = pcOther.array[i];
```

is wrong, because that just copies references, so after altering one object, copy of it will be altered too. I want to avoid that.

I'd love to use different structure for this, but it has to be dynamically allocated array of int*

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` and you're done.

Comment: You need to describe what you intend `array` to represent.   Yes, I know it is a pointer to a pointer.   But what are you USING it for?   A 2D array?  An array of pointers that each point to a single `int`?  Or what?   My guess is that the statement `*array[i] = pcOther.*array[i]` needs to be rewritten as `*(array[i]) = *(pcOther.array[i])` but - since it is not clear what you are trying to achieve -  that is only a guess.

Comment: You would be better off using a standard container.   But, saying that, doesn't help you understand the problem in your code.

Comment: *I have to create a copy constructor for my object,* -- What about an assignment operator also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the memcpy(),

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

or

```
*array[i] = *(pcOther.array[i])
```

for e.g.

```
DTable::DTable(DTable & pcOther) {
    s_name = pcOther.s_name + "_copy";
    size = pcOther.size;
    array = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = new int;
        *array[i] = *(pcOther.array[i]);
        // or
        memcpy ( array[i], pcOther.array[i] , sizeof(int)*1 );
    }
}
```